Azure Route Server
How to view the current routing preference configuration in Azure Route Server?
I have tried Az PowerShell cmdlets but didn't find the right direct cmdlet to view the current routing preference configuration in Azure Route Server?

Oh I just found the answer in official Azure document itself. Get-AzRouteServer cmdlet is provided to view the current routing preference configuration.
Source of the information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/route-server/hub-routing-preference-powershell#view-routing-preference-configuration
